# When should a v2.0 be released as opposed to a v1.0?

Tags: versioning

I'm talking about Version Control. What updates or refreshes can be deemed "important" enough to justify a version 2.0 of an application software as compared to a version 1.1? Is there a set criteria or is it subjective to the developers?

Comment: Read up on Semantic Versioning - http://semver.org

Comment: "Version control" refers to the process of storing/tracking different versions of your software, facilitated by software like Git or SVN. You are talking about "versioning". And I second @MartinSmith's link to semver.org.